# websphere JMS configuration error

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-8

On WAS 8.5.5, windows machine, When configuring JMS -> "Connection factories" I see the below error. Due to some error previously had to recreate the whole profile again, previously when I have configured I didn't see this issue. This time I also included the cipher configuration, which I had not included previously `SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256` its broken and throws the error below.

```
[7/26/17 21:37:43:643 IST] 000000fa SystemOut     O 21:37:43.643
[DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] ERROR
o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS
Connection for destination 'jms/ICMP_Document_Update_Dest' - retrying
using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=159,
maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue
manager 'TL4' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'null'.;
nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ
call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2400'
('MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE').
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to
connect to queue manager 'TL4' with connection mode 'Client' and host
name 'null'.    at
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:580)
~[com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.jar:na]     at
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:216)
~[com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.jar:na]     at
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.getConnectOptions(WMQConnection.java:1409)
~[com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.jar:na]    at
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:339)
~[com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.jar:na]    at
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQXAConnection.<init>(WMQXAConnection.java:70)
~[com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.jar:na]    at
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:190)
~[com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.jar:na]  at
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6194)
~[com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.jar:na]  at
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createProviderXAConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:102)
~[com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.jar:na]  at
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createXAConnectionInternal(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:373)
~[com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.jar:na]   at
com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(MQXAConnectionFactory.java:98)
~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.1.0.2 - k710-002-120928]  at
com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnection.createConnection(JMSManagedConnection.java:1499)
~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]    at
com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnection.<init>(JMSManagedConnection.java:352)
~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]    at
com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnectionFactory.createUnifiedManagedConnection(JMSManagedConnectionFactory.java:1301)
~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]    at
com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(JMSManagedConnectionFactory.java:682)
~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]    at
com.ibm.ejs.jms.WMQJMSRAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(WMQJMSRAManagedConnectionFactory.java:702)
~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]    at
com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:2160)
~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]    at
com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1838)
~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]    at
com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3802)
~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]    at
com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3078)
~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]    at
com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1548)
~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]    at
com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1031)
~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]    at
com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryHandle.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactoryHandle.java:256)
~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]    at
org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
~[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.createSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:413)
~[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.refreshSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:398)
~[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:915)
[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.recoverAfterListenerSetupFailure(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:890)
[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1061)
[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:809) [na:1.7.0] Caused by:
com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with
compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2400'
('MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE').  at
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:204)
~[com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.jar:na]     ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The
native JNI library 'mqjbnd' was not found. For a client installation
this is expected. [3=mqjbnd]    at
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$1.run(LocalMQ.java:307)
~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.jar:7.1.0.2 - k710-002-120928]  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:396)
~[na:1.7.0]     at
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise_inner(LocalMQ.java:268)
~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.jar:7.1.0.2 - k710-002-120928]  at
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise(LocalMQ.java:230)
~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.jar:7.1.0.2 - k710-002-120928]  at
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.<init>(LocalMQ.java:1174)
~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.jar:7.1.0.2 - k710-002-120928]  at
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalServer.<init>(LocalServer.java:193)
~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.jar:7.1.0.2 - k710-002-120928]  at
sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor26.newInstance(Unknown Source)
~[na:na]    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:58)
~[na:1.7.0]     at
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:542)
~[na:2.6 (10-05-2016)]  at
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:717)
~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.1.0.2 - k710-002-120928]    at
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:651)
~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.1.0.2 - k710-002-120928]    at
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:167)
~[com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.jar:na]  at
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6151)
~[com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.jar:na]  ... 22 common frames
omitted Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mqjbnd (Not found
in java.library.path)   at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1256)
~[na:1.7.0]
```

not sure what am I missing. kindly suggest.

Comment: More info about your configuration is needed to answer your question,  What version of WAS?  What OS and Java?  What cipher suite(s) are you configuring?  How are you configuring them?

Comment: Using the 'default messaging provider'. I have updated the page with information. thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Raghuveer The error of interest is `JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ
call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2400'
('MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE')`.  You do not mention what the version is of the queue manager you connect to (`TL4` is the name from the errors).  At certain maintenance levels of all currently supported versions of MQ many cipherspecs became unsupported by default including all `SSL` and `NULL` cipherspecs. `SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256` would translate to `TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256`.  Provide full version of MQ queue manager and I can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: @JoshMc I have not added any cipher now and got it working since it was a local ENV.